# Make auto increment fill previously deleted number

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using unused primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967588/using-unused-primary-keys)

I created a table with an id column with auto increment
Now when I deleted the rows with the id's 8,12,30 in that table.

Now when I insert a new record I want to insert the next record into 8 then 12 etc..

Is there a way to get MySQL auto increment to do this for me?

I tried to set autoincrement to some number, but I don't want to do it that way.

Comment: read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967588/using-unused-primary-keys/12967713#12967713

Comment: Autoincrement really only does what its name says - i++. So you are not going to be able to get it to fill the gaps left by deleted entries.

Comment: Just don't be obsessive about those gaps, it simply doesn't worth it :)

Comment: @biziclop the second time I've seen this question tonight. Weird gap obsessors out there.

Comment: @dngfng yes i saw that answer but i want to fill the gaps also means i just want to check first the missing numbers and then starting from max number of that row..

Comment: Also we don't mind spelling and grammer mistakes (especially due to the international nature). Please at least have the curtesy to use Capital letters and use paragraphs to make it more readable!

Comment: There are plenty natural numbers in the universe so why be obsessed with filling those gaps?

Comment: BTW, will these numbers be used as foreign keys?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to use an auto-incrementing column then. If you want to fill in the gaps, set it to an int column and handle the logic in stored proc or insert.

### EDIT:

Since it's an int column, you can order them numerically. Just do a `SELECT Ids FROM Table Order By Ids` to get all of the Ids and check for the gaps in the returned dataset.

There's probably a smoother way of doing this, but you could loop the results with a cursor and compare to an `INT` variable that increments throughout the loop. When you find a gap (no match) - break the loop and use that `INT` value as your `INSERT` id.

I won't write your code for you, but those are some steps to get you going in the right direction. It should be a really basic bit of programming you should be able to handle.

Hope this helps.

### EDIT #2:

As others have noted, your best move is to just leave the gaps. Unless there's some cap on the table as far as length and Ids MUST be 1-30 (weird), leave it alone. There's no benefit to filling in the gaps.

### EDIT #3:

One more thing to consider: if you really do have to keep 1-30 for some reason, don't delete your rows. Add a column to flag each row as active or not and then just update the rows that are inactive when you need to and then flag them as active. This is VERY hacky, but your requirement is kinda hacky, so...

Comment: will you please post the logic here to find the missing columns in auto increment such that i can create a stored procedure or i can use it in insert command too @yatrix

Comment: @Yatrix, do think removing gaps is essential for allowing the user to move through the rows in the forward and backward direction? Eg. scroll through the image? Or is there another way?

Comment: @Vass I would _never_ remove the gaps in the ID field. I'd leave it as an auto-incrementing field and keep it simple. As far as scrolling through an unknown number of images, you would use pagination for that. So, you make an api call that hits the database and grabs the first 10 records, you scroll (or hit the next page button), then you ask for the next 10 and so on. If you wanted to maintain an order for the records in db for some reason, I would create an "Order" or "Sort" column or something like that. Then you may care about filling in the gaps, depending on your need.

Comment: @Yatrix, thanks, and if there are lots of images, an efficient query would be to simply add a *limit* to the query to return eg 10 records? And how would that be based around the 'current image' position? With a range maybe?..

Answer (score 3):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/3f071/1

Set `@x` to the smallest unused value:

```
SET @x = (
  SELECT MIN(t1.id+1)
  FROM      t t1
  LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t2.id = t1.id + 1
  WHERE t2.id IS NULL
);

INSERT INTO t(id) VALUES (@x);
```

Set `@x` to the smallest unused value which is in a gap, otherwise return `NULL` to use MySQL's autoincrement mechanism:

```
SET @x = (
  SELECT IF( MIN(t1.id-1) = 0, NULL, MIN(t1.id-1) )
  FROM      t t1
  LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t2.id = t1.id - 1
  WHERE t2.id IS NULL
);

INSERT INTO t(id) VALUES (@x);
```

Of course you have to wrap these into transactions if you don't want to shoot yourself in the foot or wherever you like.

Answer (score 2):

well `AUTO_INCREMENT` behaves like that. it doesn't fill any gaps on your deleted data. The best way you can do is to create a logic that will satisfy your needs (*filling of gaps*).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer @john woo i will create and use that logic in my table..thanks for your help

Comment: @user1736927 no, please don't do that.  An ID is just an opaque number, and shouldn't have any intrinsic meaning.  Just let those gaps stay there.