# php auto generate number from my sql db

Tags: php, mysql

I need help in the following query in php. I want to create auto number like 0001, 0002.
I am using this query

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(cast(registration_code as decimal)) id FROM accounts ";  
    if($result = mysql_query($query))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        $count = $row['id'];
        $count = $count+1;

        $code_no = str_pad($count, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

It is working right but the problems is that when i delete any number like 0001, 0002, 0003 and i delete 0002 this create 0004 i want this will create deleted number i mean 0001 to 0003 if missing any that creat

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a "gap" in running counter with SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312101/how-to-find-a-gap-in-running-counter-with-sql)

Comment: its because you  have already stored numbers upto 0003  that determine 003 as its max number. Thus so even you only have 2 numbers left etc.001,003 . It would definetly get 003 as it max thus adding +1 to it will gain you 0004  using MAX() function.

Comment: Since you use the MAX function you will always get the bigger number created. If you need to recycle deleted numbers, I think you should keep a list of deleted numbers and then pick the smaller one from this list. If this list is empty, you use the above sql statement.

Comment: @Rohit - if you think the English could be improved, why not edit the question? For many SO users, English is not the first language. This question is pretty clear...

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: your are finding largest number if you delete 0002 but still largest number is 0003 then next number will be 0004

Comment: yes i have already stored till 0003, i have delete 0002 now when i create new it create 0004 but i want i create the missing number like i deleted 0002 then go on

Comment: @DavidM it was not clear to me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fragmentation of id's (auto\_increment column) in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824600/fragmentation-of-ids-auto-increment-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

used this query

```
SELECT ( accounts1.registration_code + 1) as gap_starts_at, 
       (SELECT MIN( accounts3.registration_code) -1 FROM arrc_vouchers  accounts3 WHERE  accounts3.registration_code >  accounts1.registration_code) as gap_ends_at
FROM arrc_vouchers  accounts1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  accounts2.registration_code FROM arrc_vouchers  accounts2 WHERE  accounts2.registration_code =  accounts1.registration_code + 1)
HAVING gap_ends_at IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Go fancy. Write a trigger to update next auto increment value on insert. Write trigger on delete to update the next auto increment value to the deleted id if it is lower than the current next auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to fill spaces of deleted auto increment primary no.

You can read this references..

[Make auto increment fill previously deleted number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969161/make-auto-increment-fill-previously-deleted-number)

[How to fill in the “holes” in auto-incremenet fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841104/how-to-fill-in-the-holes-in-auto-incremenet-fields)