# Add deleted record to auto increment table

Tags: mysql

I have a table having id set to auto increment.

I have records 1 to 10 and I have deleted records 3 and 7.

So is their any way I can add records 3 and 7 again?

Comment: why are you trying to do that? what's the use case?

Comment: Assumptions, as I understand you, you want the deleted records back, if not committed through DB side, you can roll back, if committed, then, sorry your records are gone...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reuse auto\_increment values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743121/how-to-reuse-auto-increment-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to "force" the id.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, field1) VALUES (3, "value"); // id = 3
```

But if you let the id "null" or not set, it will be incremented :

```
INSERT INTO table (field1) VALUES ("value"); // id = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql You can override  the auto-increment id simply assingning  the value you need .. this is perfectly legal  ..

so you can insert  your row with id 3 and 7  using

```
  insert into your_table (id, col1, col2 ..) values (3, 'value_for_col1', 'value_for_col2'...)
```

Answer (score 0):

the autoincrement only works if no value is specified for the field, in other words you can insert the specifying the value of the field with autoincrement, example: insert in `db`.`banks` (`id`, `description`,`status`, `created_at`,`updated_at`) values ('3', 'Central Bank', '1', '2017-04-14 10:30:22', null);